# Firebase App Check breaking the app on android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-check

I am trying to use Firebase App Check on android. Following the steps mentioned on [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android) link prevents the app to work as intended and just by removing the library from dependencies and three-line code mentioned in the above link app starts working again as intended. I have a `RecyclerView` in the `MainActivity` that uses `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` from the Firebase UI database library and it just stops working. I don't get the necessary items in my `RecyclerView`. I have the below code in my `Application` class's `onCreate` method. What should I do to make Firebase App Check work without breaking the functionality of the app?

```
 FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();
        firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
                SafetyNetAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance());
```

Answer (score -1):

Also install DebugAppCheckProviderFactory

```
 FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context)
        val firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance()
        firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
            DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance())
        firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
            SafetyNetAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance())
```

NOTE : Make sure your Firebase Libraries are upto updated.. then try again.. it should work.